# Error: Could not find or load main class prism.PrismCL Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prism.PrismCL

Tags: python, java, environment-variables

I am trying to run PRISM (https://www.prismmodelchecker.org/) from the command line. When I open the GUI version it seems to work fine.

I get the following error when running the prism.bat file from the command line:

Error: Could not find or load main class prism.PrismCL
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prism.PrismCL

I have the environment variable JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2
I have tried changing this to have a \bin on the end, but I got the same error.
(Very little idea what environment variables do).

Does anyone know how to fix this please? I am running windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Go to prism/bin folder and open the executable prism file. Edit line number 6 to your installation directory instead of the current one:

```
# PRISM home directory
PRISM_DIR="/Users/dxp/prism/prism/prism"
```

in my case `/Users/me/Documents/prism-4.7-osx64`

Now run a prism example again. From python, for example:

```
from subprocess import call
call([prism, file,formula])
```

and you should get:

```
PRISM
=====

Version: 4.7
Date: Fri Jun 17 03:49:12 BST 2022
Hostname: me-MacBook-Air.local
Memory limits: cudd=1g, java(heap)=1g
```